# Magento 2 CE customer update REST API not validating the password

Tags: php, rest, magento2

Magento2 CE REST API for customer information updation not validating the given password with an actual password, it accepts everything. Where in web if the user wants to change the email address of his account, Magento will ask the password and validate it. If we give the wrong password it won't allow us to change password.

```
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization: Bearer "customerToken"

Method: PUT <base_url>/rest/V1/customers/:customerID

Request:
{
  "customer": {
    "id": "45338",
    "email": "test230720195@yopmail.com",
    "firstname": "Updatetest",
    "lastname": "Testing",
    "websiteId": 1
  },
  "password": "qawsedrf!"
}
```

Is any other API can do customer info updation with password validation?

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to validate password in this request? As I know it is not required, so if you don't want update it just don't add to the body.

Comment: In web, if user wants to change the email address of his account, it will ask password to validate with user. If we give wrong password it won't allow us to change password.

Answer (score 0):

To reset customer password you can use the following request

```
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization: Bearer "authToken"

Method: PUT <base_url>/rest/V1/customers/me/password

Request:
{
  "currentPassword": "string",
  "newPassword": "string"
}
```

Note auth token here is a value you are getting with

```
/V1/integration/customer/token
```

And for the request in your question, you should use token from

```
/V1/integration/admin/token
```